# Splitting of primes in finite extensions of Noetherian normal rings

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $A/B$ be a finite extension between noetherian normal rings. Let ${\frak p}$ be a prime of $B$ and ${\frak P}$ be the *unique* prime of $A$ lying over ${\frak p}$.

Let $e \colon= [k(A) \colon k(B)]$, where we denote by $k(A)$ (resp. $k(B)$) the fractional field of $A$ (resp. $B$) be the degree of the extension.

Q. Does the following equality hold as the ideal of $A$?$\colon$

### \begin{equation*}
{\frak P}^e = {\frak p},
\end{equation*}

where ${\frak P}^e$ is defined to be the ideal generated by $g_{i_1} \cdots g_{i_e}$'s with each $g_{i_j}$ being a member of generators of ${\frak P}$.

Comment: What is a 'normal' ring?

Comment: Consider $\mathbb{Z}[i]/\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathfrak{p}=(3)$?

Comment: @Servaes an integral domain that is integrally closed inside its field of fractions

Answer (score 0):

Note that by "$\mathfrak{P}$ the unique prime of A lying above $\mathfrak{p}$" you are actually choosing special ideals $\mathfrak{p}$, because it can happen that $\mathfrak{p}$ factors as a product of multiple distinct prime ideals lying above it.

The answer to your question is: No.

As an example consider integer ring $A$ of a number field as extensions of $\mathbb{Z}=:B$: $A$ is a Dedekind domain (Noetherian normal integral domain of Krull dimension $\leq 1$) as required.

We call a prime $\mathfrak{p}$ of $B$ **completely ramified** if it exhibits the property you describe above, i.e. $\mathfrak{p}A=\mathfrak{P}^e$. But there are other behaviours a prime of $B$ can exhibit: If we assume that there is just one prime $\mathfrak{P}$ lying above $\mathfrak{p}$, that could also be the ideal $\mathfrak{p}A$, in which case we would call $\mathfrak{p}$ **inert**.

For an example in the Gaussian integers, you can check out the [Wikipedia article about the splitting of primes in Galois extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_of_prime_ideals_in_Galois_extensions)